# Как правильно присоединить к html-коду php-файл для отправки сообщений с сайта?

Tags: php, html

Как подключить к форме в html php-файл, для отправки сообщений с сайта?
В *index.html* имеется следующая форма отправки сообщений:

```
<form>  
<input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя&#46;&#46;&#46;">  
<input type="email" placeholder="Ваш Email&#46;&#46;&#46;">  
<textarea placeholder="Ваше сообщение&#46;&#46;&#46;"></textarea>  
<input type="submit" value="Отправить &rarr;" class="dropsubmitbtn">  
</form>
```

Файл *send_mail.php* выглядит так:

```
<?php  
$webmaster_email = "mail@mail.ru";  
$feedback_page = "index.html";  
$error_page = "error.html";  
$thankyou_page = "thanks.html";  
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;  
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;  
$comments = $_REQUEST['message'] ;  
function isInjected($str) {  
    $injections = array('(\n+)',  
    '(\r+)',  
    '(\t+)',  
    '(%0A+)',  
    '(%0D+)',  
    '(%08+)',  
    '(%09+)'  
    );  
    $inject = join('|', $injections);  
    $inject = "/$inject/i";  
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {  
        return true;  
    }  
    else {  
        return false;  
    }  
}  
// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {  
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );  
}  
// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.  
elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($comments)) {  
header( "Location: $error_page" );  
}
// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {  
header( "Location: $error_page" );  
}  
// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.  
else {  
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Message from your Atlas site",    
  $name, $comments, "From: $email_address" );  
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );  
}  
?>
```

Comment: @Five_floor, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Так:

    <form method="post" action="send_mail.php" name="send-mail-form" id="send-mail-form">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно сказал [[@makregistr](/users/1413/makregistr)](/users/1413/makregistr) надо так:

```
<form method="post" action="send_mail.php" name="send_mail_form">  
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя&#46;&#46;&#46;">  
<input type="email" name="email_address" placeholder="Ваш Email&#46;&#46;&#46;">  
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Ваше сообщение&#46;&#46;&#46;"></textarea>  
<input type="submit" value="Отправить &rarr;" class="dropsubmitbtn">  
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш ответ мне помог.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас уже можно по-другому сделать. С той же формой и без перезагрузки страницы:

**JS**

```
function sendMail(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'send_mail.php',
        data : $('form').serialize,
        success : function(response) { alert(response); }        
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form>  
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя&#46;&#46;&#46;">  
    <input type="email" placeholder="Ваш Email&#46;&#46;&#46;">  
    <textarea placeholder="Ваше сообщение&#46;&#46;&#46;"></textarea>  
    <input type="button" value="Отправить &rarr;" onclick="" class="dropsubmitbtn">  
</form>
```

jQuery скрипт просто отправляет данные на РНР-обработчик и возвращает ответ.